# Symfony2 Timestable trait: "Column 'createdAt' cannot be null"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, traits

I have a pretty standard Entity with the correct imports:

```
/**
 * Budhaz\aMailerBundle\Entity\Instance
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Instance {
    use TimestampableEntity;

    /** @ORM\Id @ORM\GeneratedValue @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    private $id;
...
}
```

But I would like to remove the createdAt (and updatedAt) from my form so the user don't and can't set them, so I remove it from the InstanceForm:

```
class InstanceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('startAt')
            ->add('endAt')
            //->add('createdAt')
            //->add('updatedAt')
            ->add('campaign')
        ;
    }
...
}
```

But now I have this error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'createdAt' cannot be null

createdAt and updatedAt should automaticaly be set by Doctrine, but it stays null, anyone know why?

Comment: Show please annotations for createdAt and updatedAt fields in Entity class

Comment: I don't have them because it's a [trait](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/timestampable.md).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to set the values within the class manually. Then you can tell doctrine to set the new value before every update:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
    $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function setUpdatedAtValue() {
    $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
}
```

Comment: I don't have to add the setter as I use a trait but I had to initilize the variables, thanks.

Comment: I overlooked that. You're right. In that case you only need to initialize the variables.

Comment: @insertusernamehere but they did not mention that in the trait doc, it's weird!

Comment: There is a problem with this answer although it works well, if we take the case of `Blameable` would you inject the user object into the constructor to set it as you did ?

Answer (score 13):

## app/config/config.yml

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
   orm:
      default:
          timestampable: true
```

Comment: please describe what this does.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle that contains timestampable and others features without a pain)

Answer (score 5):

You need to check if the bundle is installed. If not, run:
`composer require stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle`

It should create file: `app/config/packages/stof_doctrine_extensions.yaml` with the content:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: en_US
    orm:
        default:
            timestampable: true
```